# click handler not fire (partial view)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a `View` and `Desk.js` file with javascript code.
In the `View`:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KazBilet/Desk.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the `Desk.js` file:

```
$(function () {
    $('.wraper').load('/desk/getsessionscreen');
    toggleSession();
});

function toggleSession() {
    alert('a');
    $('.sched a').on('click', function () {
        var target = $(this);
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('.sched a').not(target).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        });

        setStateForStepButton();
    });
}
```

The elements with `sched` class and `a` tags contains in partial view which loaded in `wraper` div element.

The problem in that `click` handler not fire, but `alert` calls fine. How to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant `HTML(View)` code as well? Also, the logic written inside `click` handler is not right. Just check your code again, if you don't know what i mean i'll try to explain :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your click subscription code outside. You don't even need to wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
$('.sched').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var target = $(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.sched a').not(target).each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

    setStateForStepButton();
});


$(function () {
    $('.wraper').load('/desk/getsessionscreen', function() {
        toggleSession();
    });

});

function toggleSession() {
    alert('a');
}
```

Also notice the correct overload I am using for the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method if you want to register lively:

```
$('.sched').on('click', 'a', function () {
```

Also note that if you want to call the `toggleSession` function when the AJAX call succeeds you should use the success callback of the `.load` method.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, why my code not works. I believe that `on` method using for dynamically created elements. Yes, it's works if I call `toggleSession` in the success callback, but it's also works if I wrote direct `click` handler: `$('.sched a').click(...)`

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you are using an overload of the .on method which doesn't work as .live. And you have not put your code inside the AJAX success handler. So at the moment you are calling your .on method the AJAX has not yet finished.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call toggleSession() in the callback of load, otherwise the content might not have been loaded yet, so your selector can't find the desired element.

```
$('.wraper').load('/desk/getsessionscreen', function () {
    toggleSession();
});
```

Comment: there are a `on`. I think  it's uses for this situation

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct, but I had some problems in the past with `on()`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sched a', function () {
    var target = $(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.sched a').not(target).each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

    setStateForStepButton();
});
```

Also, if you are trying to set the class `selected` only to the `a` clicked, I should rewrite your code as:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sched a', function () {
    $('.sched a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    setStateForStepButton();
});
```

And as yan.kun said, call the function on the callback of `load()`